# How to import `.a` file to CMake in C++?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, box2d, .a

I've generated `libBox2D.a`. Now I want to import it to C++ project, but I don't know how. How I can import my `libBox2D.a` to my project using CMake?

Comment: Hmm... I don't think this question is too broad. It has only one topic: import `libBox2D.a` using CMake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
find_library(LIBBOX2D Box2D DIRECTORY)
```

where replace DIRECTORY with the location of `libBox2D.a`. Then you can link this library to your executable:

```
target_link_libraries(exec ${LIBBOX2D})
```

Comment: And then I can use Box2D? Do I have to do `#import <Box2D>` or something?

Comment: In you cmake file you should write something like `include_directories(dir)` where you replace dir with the directory of the header files of Box2D. Then in your source code you will do `#include <file>` where you replace the file with whatever header file you need from Box2D.

Comment: So, only what I need to do is include source code (or only headers?) and link `libBox2D.a`?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. I'm assuming you know how you want to use Box2D. I don't really know what it does. Here my answer is about how to include that external library into your project using cmake. The rest is up to you - how you want to use it and what code you want to write with it.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Also 

target_link_libraries(v4l2  /usr/lib/libv4l2wrapper.a  )
works, without prefixes